# Ajax http.responseText URL vs text

Tags: php, ajax, httpresponse

Is it possible to choose what response to get back from a PHP script called with ajax.  It is possible to say that instead of getting back what the script writes that I want the entire script to be treated as a URL and have that as the response?

I am calling a PHP script like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var http = false;
    if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
      http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else {
      http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    function LoadCalendar() {
      http.abort();
      http.open("GET", "luxcal/index.php?cP=2", true);
      http.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4) {
          /* document.getElementById('litcal').src = http.responseText; */
          document.getElementById('litcal').innerHTML = http.responseText;
        }
      }
      http.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

Loading the PHP script response in a div innerHTML works.  I would rather load the response in an iframe.  Does the http object have an option to get the URL response, e.g. http.responseURL?  I could then do `document.getElementById('litcal').src = http.responseURL`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load response in an iframe, just do it in HTML without using AJAX

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="litcal"></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('litcal').src = 'luxcal/index.php?cP=2';
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't ajax allow me to load the element asynchronously while the other parts of the page continue to load?  Originally the page was loaded with HTML but I want to do other things while the script loads.

Comment: the content of an iframe loads in an async manner as well. Specifying iframe's src won't stop your page from loading other stuff